# Calculate percentages by using JOINS result in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.4, query

I am trying to calculate percentages by joining 3 tables data to get the percentages of positive_count, negative_count, neutral_count of each user's tweets. I have succeeded in getting positive, negative and neutral counts, but failing to get the same as percentages instead of counts. Here is the query to get counts:

```
SELECT t1.u_id,count(*) as total_tweets_count
, (SELECT count(*) from t1,t2,t3 c WHERE  t1.u_id='18839785' AND 
t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id AND t3.sentiment='Positive') as pos_count
, (SELECT count(*) from t1,t2,t3 WHERE  t1.u_id='18839785' AND 
t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id AND t3.sentiment='Negative') as neg_count
, (SELECT count(*) from t1,t2,t3 WHERE  t1.u_id='18839785' AND 
t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id AND t3.sentiment='Neutral') as neu_count 
FROM t1,t2,t3 WHERE t1.u_id='18839785' AND t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND 
t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id GROUP BY t1.u_id;

 u_id | total_tweets_count | pos_count | neg_count | neu_count 
 -----------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 18839785|         88 |        38 |        25 |        25
 (1 row)
```

Now I want the same in percentages instead of counts. I have written the query in the following way but failed.

```
SELECT total_tweets_count
,pos_count, round((pos_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS 
pos_per
,neg_count, round((neg_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS 
neg_per
,neu_count, round((neu_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS 
neu_per 
FROM (SELECT count(*) as total_tweets_count
,count(a.u_id='18839785' AND a.u_id=b.u_id AND b.ts_id=c.ts_id AND 
c.sentiment='Positive') AS pos_count
,count(a.u_id='18839785' AND a.u_id=b.u_id AND b.ts_id=c.ts_id AND 
c.sentiment='Negative') AS neg_count
,count(a.u_id='18839785' AND a.u_id=b.u_id AND b.ts_id=c.ts_id AND 
c.sentiment='Neutral') AS neu_count

FROM t1,t2, t3 WHERE a.u_id='18839785' AND a.u_id=b.u_id AND 
b.ts_id=c.ts_id GROUP BY a.u_id) sub;
```

Can anyone help me out in achieving as percentages for each user data?